# What is Deadpool's sexual orientation?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, deadpool, deadpool-2016

### What actually is his sexual orientation in the movie?

The comics show a more male to male gay attraction in a lot of scenes, such as the one below:

[image]

In the movie we are shown a scene where he and Vanessa are having a, well, different experience:

And I guess this was also has some sort of connotation:

So there is all this talk about [Deadpool being Pansexual](http://www.towleroad.com/2016/02/deadpool-pansexual-antihero-gay-baiting-jokester/), but I don't see anything that really suggests that.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansexuality) states:

> Go Ask Alice! states that pansexuals can be attracted to cisgender,
>   transgender, intersex and androgynous people, and that the term
>   pansexual "is generally considered a more inclusive term than
>   bisexual"

So, from that one scene, that was with a women, are we supposed to assume that Wade Wilson is in fact pansexual? Was there anything that explicitly states as to what Deadpool was supposed to be?

I am going to say, this will require a more out of universe answer.

Comment: His orientation is comedic. It will follow The Rule of Funny.

Comment: @Politank-Z thank you for _not_ linking TV tropes. I have homework to do.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Once again, my laziness saves the day!

Comment: I remember Ryan Reynolds saying something about being "happy to have a boyfriend for Deadpool" in further movies, but I'm too lazy to find anything now.

Comment: Two words: [Polymorphous perversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphous_perversity).

Comment: Isn't the answer to that question simply "yes"?

Comment: Deadpool as far as I know would sleep with anything or anyone up to and including a Unicorn.

Comment: Dead video links...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the film's director, Tim Miller, Deadpool's sexual orientation is '[*pansexual*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansexuality)'.

> **Q.** *Can you talk about the tantalizing fireside photo that you guys put out. Does this mean it will be a very hypersexualized
> Deadpool?*
>
> **Miller:** *Pansexual! I want that quoted. Pansexual Deadpool.*
>
> <sub><sup>['Deadpool': Ryan Reynolds and Tim Miller on Footage Leaks, ‘Guardians’ Anxiety and Hyper-Violence](https://collider.com/deadpool-ryan-reynolds-tim-miller-interview/)</sup></sub>

This was confirmed by the film's producer, Simon Kinsberg

> *"Well I think your audience has seen from the materials so far the
> goal is to be as true as possible to the essence of the Deadpool
> canon. **The character, as you know, identifies as pansexual in the
> comics, and while we don't explore it in depth in this film, it's
> definitely alluded to.** Mainly in this movie we cover his love story
> with Vanessa from the comics, but it's certainly something that we
> could go deeper into in future movies and it has presence in this
> one."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Exclusive News on ‘X-Men: Apocalypse’, ‘Deadpool’, the Whole Pansexual Thing and Much More](https://collider.com/deadpool-sexuality-x-men-apocalypse-magneto-quicksilver-dad/)</sup></sub>

---

The character's co-creator, Fabian Nicieza also backs this up.

> ***He is NO sex and ALL sexes. He is yours and everyone else’s. So not
> dismissive, but rather the epitome of inclusive.***
>
> *DP brain cells are in CONSTANT FLUX. He can be gay one minute, hetero
> the next, etc. ALL ARE VALID.*
>
> *Funny how you don’t understand the character at all regardless of his
> (or your) perceived sexuality. It is why he is insane, why his memory
> is so flawed, and why he was able to survive the cancer in his system.
> It is why he can like something one minute and hate it the next. It
> has ALWAYS been a part of the character’s makeup. **You’re arguing with
> the guy who introduced the omnisexual, pansexual, heterosexual,
> homosexual, etc. aspects of the character!***
>
> <sub><sup>[Deadpool Co-Creator Waffles About the Character’s Canonical Omnisexuality](https://www.themarysue.com/deadpool-co-creator-omnisexuality/)</sup></sub>

---

There have been clues that the *sequel movie* may see Deadpool with a boyfriend.

> *“I love that about Deadpool,” said Reynolds. “I love that he can break
> any boundary. In the future, I hope we get to do that more,” he said,
> alluding to his character’s monogamous relationship with a woman
> (“Gotham” star Morena Baccarin).*
>
> ***Reynolds added that he thought it would be “nice” for Deadpool to have
> a boyfriend at some point. “I certainly wouldn’t be the guy standing
> in the way of that,” Reynolds said. “That would be great.”***
>
> *There are clues in “Deadpool” that its hero is just as interested in
> men as he is in women, but they are often handled with a wink rather
> than occupying a major plot line. Early in the movie, Deadpool
> suggests a mock fling with Wolverine and seems open to sexual
> experimentation during a sex montage (although the only partner in the
> scene is his girlfriend). “We knew that was part of the comics,” said
> one of the film’s screenwriters, Rhett Reese. “We wanted to honor that
> in the movie. But we did it in subtle ways.” Added producer Simon
> Kinberg: “There’s veiled references to it in this film. It’s in the
> DNA of the character.” Kinberg said he wouldn’t rule out showing
> Deadpool with a male companion in future installments.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ryan Reynolds on Deadpool’s Open Sexuality: A Boyfriend ‘Would Be Great’](https://variety.com/2016/film/news/deadpool-ryan-reynolds-boyfriend-1201701123/)</sup></sub>